# Can someone help me to solve 'org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:' in my case?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a table with 4 rows and columns. I compare parameters name in first column with my HasMap parameter key and if matched, then I should click on the "gear" icon in the fourth column at the same row. Looks like I lost reference for row during second parameter processing.
Initialize HashMap and add parameters for it:

```
Map <String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("param1”, "value1”);
parameters.put("param2”, "value2”);
```

Method code:

```
public void setOptionalPluginParameters (Map <String, String> parameters) {

    Map <String, String> sorted_parameters = new TreeMap<String, String>(parameters);
    List <WebElement>  table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));

    for (WebElement table_row : table_rows) {
            String table_parameter_name = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-2")).getText();
            for (String key : sorted_parameters.keySet())
            {
                if (table_parameter_name.equals(key)) {
                    String parameter_value = sorted_parameters.get(key);
                    System.out.println("Hash value: "+ parameter_value + " By Hash Key: " + key);
                    WebElement gear = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-5 i.fa-gear"));
                    gear.click(); // <------error here during processing second parameter-------->
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("value")));
                    driver.findElement(By.id("value")).clear();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("value")).sendKeys(parameter_value);
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Result: **org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

I tried a lot of approaches to solve it, without any success:

- Thread.sleep();
- try-catch;
- try-catch in loop;
- Found item again in loop;
- driver.navigate().refresh();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stale element happens when you are document (HTML) changes. so in your case you have a click action inside for loop. That modifies the html document.

This changes reference of all elements, so you have to re-identify all elements. use below soluton

```
public void setOptionalPluginParameters (Map <String, String> parameters) {

    Map <String, String> sorted_parameters = new TreeMap<String, String>(parameters);
    List <WebElement>  table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));
    WebElement table_row;
    int count=0;
    while (count!=table_rows.size()) {
            table_row = table_rows.get(count);
            count+=1;
            String table_parameter_name = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-2")).getText();
            for (String key : sorted_parameters.keySet())
            {
                if (table_parameter_name.equals(key)) {
                    String parameter_value = sorted_parameters.get(key);
                    System.out.println("Hash value: "+ parameter_value + " By Hash Key: " + key);
                    WebElement gear = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-5 i.fa-gear"));
                    gear.click(); // <------error here during processing second parameter-------->      
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("value")));
                    driver.findElement(By.id("value")).clear();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("value")).sendKeys(parameter_value);
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();
                    table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));
                    break;
                }
            table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));
            
            }
       }
```

Comment: I tried your approach. "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" issue is happened on the "gear.click()" code row. I also add try-catch and then it happened in catch block. Works good with first parameter, but failed with second.

Comment: could you add wait until clickable for that gear?

Comment: you used the code as it is ? just cross check

Comment: don't make any changes

Comment: i made one more change , i am not sure how your for loop works , so added the find table_rows out side the if condition also

Comment: Still getting this error (row -> "gear.click()"), using your last code variant.

Comment: can you add time.sleep(3) before the click and see if that works ? with the above code

Comment: and also before table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));

Comment: just to see if wait is helping , if that helps then add wait

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working. Added "Thread.sleep(3000)" before "gear.click" and "table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));", small change for my needs I removed "break", because sometime it causes fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your element have been temporary inaccessable or removed from DOM structure.

This is solution i usually use when facing this problem. Try to load the element second time:

```
try {
   # find element in here
   WebElement gear = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-5 i.fa-gear"));
   gear.click();
}catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
   # repeat a gain when it catch the error
   WebElement gear = table_row.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-grid3-col-5 i.fa-gear"));
   gear.click();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, error is occurred again, in catch block (first row - WebElement gear).

Comment: List <WebElement>  table_rows = driver.findElements(By.className("x-grid3-row"));

Comment: Check the list element. May be the problem not because of gear element. May be table_row what temporary removed from DOM.